# Unable to run react server and node backend at the same time using concurrently

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server, concurrently

This is my node backend package json file

"scripts": {
"start": "node server",
"server":"nodemon server",
"client":"npm start --perfix client",
"dev":"concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client""
},

This is my react package.json file

```js
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080/"
}
```

I have set my PORT variable to 8080 . And when i run npm run dev, i get this error in terminal

```
[1] node:events:504
[1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[1]       ^
[1]
[1] Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8080
[1]     at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1330:16)
[1]     at listenInCluster (node:net:1378:12)
[1]     at Server.listen (node:net:1465:7)
[1]     at Function.listen (C:\xampp\htdocs\node\own\expense\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:635:24)
[1]     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\node\own\expense\server.js:18:5)
[1]     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
[1]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
[1]     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
[1]     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
[1]     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
[1] Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
[1]     at emitErrorNT (node:net:1357:8)
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
[1]   code: 'EADDRINUSE',
[1]   errno: -4091,
[1]   syscall: 'listen',
[1]   address: '::',
[1]   port: 8080
[1] }
[1] npm run client exited with code 1
```

I am trying to run react server and node server at the same time using concurrently. But I am getting the same error even though I tried changing ports many and times and also killed all the processes running on that port.
Am i doing anything wrong ?

I have removed all the other code form package.json file from both client and server and only kept related code.

Please let me any way from which i can run both react and node servers from npm run dev command ?

Comment: _"npm start --perfix client"_... did you mean `--prefix`

Comment: Are you trying to run the React dev server and Express on the same port? If so, you cannot do that

Comment: No. React dev server is running on default 3000. I didn't change that. My feeling  is that the node server is getting called to run twice somehow. Bcoz when i try to close server using ctrc C , i get this line,  [0] Terminate batch job (Y/N)? Terminate batch job (Y/N)? npm run server exited with code 1

Comment: Did you fix that `perfix` typo?

Comment: I didn't know it was a typo . I added it intentionally. Anyways I tried removing --prefix also. Still receiving the same error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question so it shows what you actually have